# Sending php generated form data via Ajax from Dialog box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi Guys any help on this? I have a dialog box triggered by a button click that calls my php script to generate a form which needs to be filled and submitted. I want to do the sending and conformation via Ajax. I have been recoding and researching for a few days but nothing on StackExchange or other websites help me with it.
Here's the code:

Dialog box snippet;

```
$k('#CreateTable').click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
         var Call =  $k('#CreateTable').attr('value');//.attr('id');

         var util = $k(this).attr('id');//.attr('id');

         $k('#dialog').dialog({
             autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Running Utility for: '+Call,
            modal: true,
            width: 450,
            close: function(event, ui) {
             $k("#dialog").dialog('destroy');//event.target
            }//END CLOSE

        }).dialog('open');
        var utility = { 'utility' : util };
        $k.ajax({
                  type: "post",
                  url: "inc/runUtilities.php",
                  dataType: "html",
                  data: utility,
                  success: function(data) {
                        $k('#DlgTxt').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
                  }
        });
            //return false;
        });//END DIALOG
```

The PHP snippet;

```
$show .=  "<form id='cContact' name='cContact' method='post'>";
    // action='".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."'
    $show .= '<table align="center" width="425" border="0">
       ';

        $query = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM `".$_SESSION['WorkTable']."`"; 
        if($output = mysqli_query($this->MySQLCxn->MySQLCxn, $query))
        {
            $columns = array();
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($output))
            {
                if($row['Field'] == 'id') {}
                else
               $show .= '
                <tr>
                  <td width="175"><div align="right">'.@$row['Field'].':</div></td>
                  <td width="155">
                    <input type="text" name="'.@$row['Field'].'" placeholder="'.@$row['Field'].'" />
                  </td>
                  <td width="115">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                ';
            }
        }


    $show .= '
        <tr>
          <td>Submit </td><td>

          <button type="button" id="cContactSbmt" onclick="doSubmitForm(this); return false;" name="cContactSbmt" value="cContactSbmt">Create contact</button>


          <!-- <input type="submit" class="button" value="Save" name="submit"> -->
          </td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </table></form>
      <div id="thanks">

      </div>
       ';
```

And the JQuery that i am currently using trying to have it call my php to process the form being sent.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); 

(function($j){
 $j(document).ready(function() {
    $j("#cContactSbmt").click(function(e){//'click',
         e.preventDefault();
             alert('cContactSbmt clicked...');
         $j.ajax ({
          type:"POST",
          url:"inc/runUtilities.php",
          data: $j(this).serialize(),
          success: function(msg){
            $j("#thanks").html(msg)
            $j(this).modal('hide');
          },
          error: function(){
            alert("failure");
          }
        });
      });


});
```

})($j);

For some reason its not working nothing showing up in the console as well.
again: i have a dialog box that gets populated via Ajax with a php generated from that needs to get submitted to another php script that is to process it and reply to the dialogs.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Guys so I got it working with the following changes:
On the form;

```
<button id="cContactSbmt" onClick="doContactsCreate(\'#cContact\')" type="button" class="form-submit"  name="cContactSbmt" value="cContactSbmt">Create contact</button>
```

I added the onclick method with a callback to a function doContactsCreate(\'#cContact\'), which has the id of the form passed to it.

```
function doContactsCreate(obj)
{
     alert(obj+': cContactSbmt clicked...');
    /* */
    var frmData = $k(obj).serialize();
         $k.ajax ({
          type:"POST",
          url:"inc/runUtilities.php",
          data: frmData,
          success: function(data){
          $k("#thanks").html(data);
          console.log(data);
            $k(obj).modal('hide');
          },
          error: function(){
            alert("failure");
          }
        });

}
```

I've just enclosed the JQuery code in this function definition and placed it outside the

```
(function($k){
 $k(document).ready(function() {
//rest of JQuery code
})($k);
```

Don't know why but i think that was the main problem

Answer (score 2):

your php ist not outputting ("echoing") anything. you need to `echo` whatever you want to return to your ajax-call.

**update:** plus for debugging try to log the returned data in every `success` callback, for example:

```
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: i would bet money that he returns the $show somewhere...also your "answer" would be more like a comment.

Comment: @TopQuestions maybe - but I've seen this exact mistake by many people that are new to ajax.

Comment: @northkilidonan wasn't meant to be rude sorry, reading it again sound very rude :/

Comment: @TopQuestions well, if it's the solution of his problem - it's an answer. if it isn't, it still is. lol.

Comment: @GeraldoIsaaks then please provide your full code and try to debug your ajax callbacks as i mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I've bend the last our trying delegate and trigger and bind /on mixes... still nothing.
@northkildonan i've tried debug, still nothing comes up...

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add an echo to the end of your php snippet..

```
echo $show;
```

This echoed html will then be available in your ajax function in the success callback function... as the variable "data"

```
success: function(data) {
  $k('#DlgTxt').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
}
```

Also you may need to use jQuery .on() in your click function..to submit the form..

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$j("body").on("click", "#cContactSbmt", function(){

});
```

Hope this helps....

Comment: Guys i have spent about 2 days just on this code please have a good look at it - i'm only about a year with JQuery so i may be missing some. as to the php code - echoing - the code is a snippet from a class that does quite a lot so i left out the other code...